# Special Layout directory for HTC Sensation

Tags: android, android-layout, size, screen

I'm trying to convert my application layout from the one for Galaxy to another for HTC Sensation.
I have created a folder `layout-540x960` according to the screen size but i get this error: `invalid resource directory name    layout-540x960`
How it can be solved?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give a layout directory any name you want. Please read this article to find out how to support different screen sizes:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

> The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge. For example, layouts for an extra large screen should go in layout-xlarge/.
>
> Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are deprecated and you should instead use the swdp configuration qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your layout resources. For example, if your multi-pane tablet layout requires at least 600dp of screen width, you should place it in layout-sw600dp/.